# Saving json array output to txt file and getting errors when attempting to parse

Tags: arrays, json, python-3.x, parsing

I am unable to parse a JSON array from a text file due to errors and my limited knowledge of JSON.

The file looks something like this [{"random":"fdjsf","random56":128,"name":"dsfjsd", "rid":1243,"rand":674,"name":"dsfjsd","random43":722, "rid":126},{"random":"fdfgfgjsf","random506":120,"name":"dsfjcvcsd", "rid":12403,"rando":670,"name":"dsfooojsd","random4003":720, "rid":120}] It has more than one object({}) in the entire array however I did not want to include all 600. The layout shown above is basically how all of them look.

```
r = s.get(getAPI, headers=header, verify=False) 
f = open('text.txt', 'w+')
f.write(r.text)
f.close


output_file = open ('text.txt', 'r')
json_array = json.load(output_file)
json_list = []
for item in json_array:
    name = "name"
    rid = "rid"
    json_items = {name:None, rid:None}
    json_items = [name] = item[name]
    json_items = [rid] = item[rid]
    json_list.append(json_items)

print(json_list)
```

I would like to loop through an array and find any time it says "name":... eventually followed by "rid":... and store those in a dictionary as key value pairs.

Errors:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a syntax error when you assign values to `json_items`, change it to:

```py
json_items[name] = item[name]
json_items[rid] = item[rid]
```